# (after) jquery get script success I don't see (deliberate) errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I don't understand why I cant see errors from my script **after success** (I google this and it just comes up with lots of answers about error handling for the event of success/error on jquery get script).

If I do this with 'any' js script

```
$.getScript('myextrascript.js',function(){console.log('got it!');});
```

Emphasis on 'any' js script (I've tried at least 12 different scripts by different people) because after my script had an error that just stopped the script (I got no console error) my first thought was does this happen just with my code?

say for example my extra script had a deliberately undeclared variable in it...

**myextrascript.js:**

```
console.log('I can see this in the console no problem');

var declaired='this variable is ok';

undeclaired='this will cause an error';

console.log("I now don't see this console log because my code has stopped");
```

I would normally see the error in the console like

```
undeclaired is undefined       myextrascript.js:3
```

But I don't see errors inside my extra scripts, Not even if I put this a line before my error

```
window.onerror=function(e,script,line){window.console.log("Error: "+e+" ("+script+":"+ line+")");}
```

Don't really have anymore ideas past this, It's really puzzling.

Comment: no, everything is 200 OK (like I said the problem isn't error on trying to get a script). I'm forcing an error to happen in that script but not seeing the error reported to the console.

Comment: Have you wrapped it in a *$(function(){});* ? it needs to happen after the DOM is ready

Comment: no I've not wrapped it (my code is as above). I've tried setting a timer to run the code in the extra script one minute after the dom is ready and I still don't see the error

Comment: Why would `undeclaired='this will cause an error';` cause an error? Is your script running in strict mode?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky - Why would the script shown need to happen after the DOM is ready?

Comment: it should cause an error!

Comment: &*$\function{(}!)=%ERR!!! console.log('<-- that would defiantly cause an error but i still see no error!');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

```
"use strict";

window.onerror=function(e,script,line){window.console.log("Error: "+e+" ("+script+":"+ line+")");}

undeclaired=1;

console.log('WINNING!');
```

I **added** "use strict"; and now it its working/broken (BROKEN JUST HOW I WANT!)

```
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: undeclaired is not defined (myextrascript.js:12)
Uncaught ReferenceError: undeclaired is not defined
```

[image]